# Copy Spark TextArea Text to another Spark TextArea

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, textarea, flex-spark

How can we copy one spark TextArea to another spark textarea while keeping the formatting. I can retrieve the text but how i can keep the format.

What I am trying achieve  is I have two spark text areas , users types in 1 with styles like (bold, italic , underline). Now when user click some additional keys like Ctrl+J or some other keys I want the text in source TextArea to another textarea while keeping the formatting applied.

Thanks in advance for help on this.

Comment: Hi Anton
really worked as I mentioned but I have a certain situation, my destination text area is an inline itemrenderer in a Datagrid. 

I tried to achieve it following way:

1. Assign the object a value 
<code>
obj.value = editor.textFlow.deepCopy() as TextFlow;
test.textFlow = obj.value;
dataCollection.addItem(obj);
</code>

2. use obj.value in itemrendere
<code><s:GridItemEditor>
<s:TextArea width="100%" height="100%" borderVisible="false" color="#000000" textFlow="{data.value}" >
</s:TextArea>'</s:GridItemEditor></code>

All I get is Object TextFlow in datagrid column , any pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try someting like this

```
        var tff:TextFlow = textArea1.textFlow.deepCopy() as TextFlow;
        textArea2.textFlow = tff;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your destination text area is an inline itemrenderer in a Datagrid you can use

```
        var tff:TextFlow = textArea1.textFlow.deepCopy() as TextFlow;
        var obj:Object = {};
        obj.textFlow = tff;
        dataGrid.dataProvider = new ArrayCollection([obj]);

<s:DataGrid id="dataGrid" x="500" width="1000" height="500">
    <s:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <s:GridItemRenderer>
                <s:TextArea id="textArea2"
                            textFlow="{data.textFlow}"
                        />
            </s:GridItemRenderer>
        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>
</s:DataGrid>
```

Comment: Tried that but not working.  Please see comments on original question. Sorry not sure how to code formatting here tried but dosent seem to work.

Comment: PS: Can add one more small question here, how can we get the HTMLText or the text with tags for styling from textarea.

Comment: TextConverter.export(editor.textFlow,TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT,ConversionType.STRING_TYPE).toString()

Comment: Give me your code and explain what exactly not working please

Comment: Actually I dropped the idea to use the Datagrid , instead i used a VGroup with dynamically added HGroups containing three different elements ( A button, textarea and an image). Thanks for all the support.